# Model not being passed back to controller mvc3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is an MVC3, VB.NET App, using razor view engine. For some reason my model is not being passed back to the controller. On the post action when I look at the variable it has 0 items in the collection. Any ideas as to why this might be???

Post Controller action looks like this:

```
  <AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
    Function EditSponsorPercs(ByVal SponPercModel As PercsCollection) As ActionResult
        '' LOGIC HERE FOR processing model
        ''
        ''
        '  db.sponsorlevels.ApplyCurrentValues(y)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("xxxxxxnsorInfo")
    End Function
```

And the view looks like this:

```
@ModelType xxxxxxx.PercsCollection

@Code
ViewData("Title") = "EditSponsorPercs"
End Code
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@<fieldset>

 <table style="width: 100%">
   <tr><td>@Html.ActionLink("Add Benefit", "AddSponBen", New With {.id = model.persCollections.ElementAt(0).idSponLevel})</td></tr>
   <tr><th style="width: 90%">Benefits Descriptions</th><th>Order</th></tr>
        @For i As Integer = 0 To Model.persCollections.Count - 1
             Dim _i = i
               @<tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%">@Html.TextAreaFor(Function(f) f.persCollections.ElementAt(_i).sponLvlPercDesc, New With {.class = "item2"})</td><td>@Html.TextAreaFor(Function(f) f.persCollections.ElementAt(_i).percOrdering, New With {.class = "num1"})</td><td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteSponBen", New With {.id = Model.persCollections.ElementAt(0).idpercLevel})</td><td></td></tr>
        Next
  </table>
 <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" /></p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

The model is set up like this:

```
Public Class PercsCollection
Private _percsCollections As New List(Of SponPercModel)
Public Property persCollections() As List(Of SponPercModel)
    Get
        Return _percsCollections
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of SponPercModel))
        _percsCollections = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Class SponPercModel
    Private _idpercLevel As Integer
    Public Property idpercLevel() As Integer
        Get
            Return _idpercLevel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _idpercLevel = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _sponLvlPercDesc As String
    Public Property sponLvlPercDesc() As String
        Get
            Return _sponLvlPercDesc
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _sponLvlPercDesc = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _idSponLevel As Integer
    Public Property idSponLevel() As Integer
        Get
            Return _idSponLevel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _idSponLevel = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _percOrdering As Integer
    Public Property percOrdering() As Integer
        Get
            Return _percOrdering
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _percOrdering = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
End Class
```

The Rendered HTML Source looks like this:

```
 <tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%"><textarea class="item2" cols="20" id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" rows="2">
 ...............</textarea><input id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" type="hidden"     value=".................." /></td><td><textarea class="num1" cols="20" id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" rows="2">
 1</textarea><input id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" type="hidden" value="1" /></td><td><a href="/Admin/DeleteSponBen/1">Delete Sponsor Benefit</a></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%"><textarea class="item2" cols="20" id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" rows="2">
 ..................</textarea><input id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" type="hidden" value=".................." /></td><td><textarea class="num1" cols="20" id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" rows="2">
 2</textarea><input id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" type="hidden" value="2" /></td><td><a href="/Admin/DeleteSponBen/1">Delete Sponsor Benefit</a></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%"><textarea class="item2" cols="20" id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" rows="2">
 ..................</textarea><input id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" type="hidden" value=".................." /></td><td><textarea class="num1" cols="20" id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" rows="2">
 3</textarea><input id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" type="hidden" value="3" /></td><td><a href="/Admin/DeleteSponBen/1">Delete Sponsor Benefit</a></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%"><textarea class="item2" cols="20" id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" rows="2">
  ..................</textarea><input id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" type="hidden" value=".................." /></td><td><textarea class="num1" cols="20" id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" rows="2">
 4</textarea><input id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" type="hidden" value="4" /></td><td><a href="/Admin/DeleteSponBen/1">Delete Sponsor Benefit</a></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%"><textarea class="item2" cols="20" id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" rows="2">
 ..................</textarea><input id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" type="hidden" value="..................(Submit your logo)" /></td><td><textarea class="num1" cols="20" id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" rows="2">
 5</textarea><input id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" type="hidden" value="5" /></td><td><a href="/Admin/DeleteSponBen/1">Delete Sponsor Benefit</a></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td style="min-height: 20px; width:80%"><textarea class="item2" cols="20" id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" rows="2">R..................</textarea><input id="sponLvlPercDesc" name="sponLvlPercDesc" type="hidden" value=".................." /></td><td><textarea class="num1" cols="20" id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" rows="2">
 6</textarea><input id="percOrdering" name="percOrdering" type="hidden" value="6" /></td><td><a                                             href="/Admin/DeleteSponBen/1">Delete Sponsor Benefit</a></td><td></td></tr>
```

The view populates fine but on the submit the model is coming back empty.. Open for ideas..

Comment: How does the HTML for the form render? Why are you doing `Dim _i = i`?

Comment: the dim _i = i just fixes the VS highlighting of i saying using an Iteration variable in the lambda expression may have unexpected results... No other reason.

Comment: By a button that passes the an Id to the calling controller function.

Comment: indeed, the generated HTML would be nice. Also, does `percsCollection` inherit from a collection class? I'm confused by the name of the model, then referencing `Model.persCollections`.

Comment: Ive edited the OP to contain the model as well as a sample of the rendered html.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want to do but 2 things: All your input and textarea generated have the same name and id in the HTML code. Is the delete link `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteSponBen", New With {.id = Model.persCollections.ElementAt(0).idpercLevel})` really what you want to do (all your delete links go to the same ID)??

Comment: That problem with the delete is the last of my concerns and is an easy fix.. I simply want the entire model to come back to the controller on post.